# migration - countable or uncountable

Tags: countability

I found out that the word "migration" can be countable and uncountable according to [oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/migration), but I didn't find any source explaining when to use countable or uncountable form.

For example, is it correct to say:

> This problem may lead to frequent migrations.

?

Comment: Context please!  Are you talking about people or animals, or something else.

Comment: I'm talking about loads on several devices and their migration from one device to another.